# Meteor wrapAsync has no method 'apply'

Tags: asynchronous, meteor

I'm trying to take an async function, wrap it and call it:

```
s3 = new AWS.S3();
Meteor.methods({
    getbuckets: function( params, buckets ) {
        var buckets = Meteor.wrapAsync(
            s3.listBuckets( params, function( err, data ) {
                if ( err ) {
                    console.log( err, err.stack ); // error
                } else {
                    return buckets;
                }
                return {};
            }) // End listBuckets
        ); // End wrapAsync

        return buckets( params );
    }
});
```

When calling the method, I'm getting this error:

> TypeError: Object # has no method 'apply'

this is pointing to the line with `buckets( params )`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Meteor.wrapAsync takes an existing asynchronous method method, such as `s3.listBuckets`. The second parameter contains the context `this` should bind to. This should work:

```
Meteor.methods({
    getbuckets: function(params) {            
        var listBuckets = Meteor.wrapAsync(s3.listBuckets, s3)
        return listBuckets(params);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`Meteor.wrapAsync` takes a function as an argument. What you are doing, is executing the function `s3.listBuckets` and passing the return value as an argument to `Meteor.wrapAsync`. Which doesn't have the prototype `Function`. So what you need to do is wrap it in an **anonymous** function, like this:

```
Meteor.methods({
    getbuckets: function( params, buckets ) {
        var buckets = Meteor.wrapAsync(
            function bucketLister (params, resolveFuture) {
                s3.listBuckets( params, function( err, data ) {
                    if ( err ) {
                        console.log( err, err.stack ); // error
                        resolveFuture(false)
                    } else {
                        resolveFuture(buckets);
                    }
                    return {};
                }) // End listBuckets
            } // End bucketLister
        ); // End wrapAsync

        return buckets( params );
    }
});
```

The function passed to `Meteor.wrapAsync` takes a function `resolveFuture` as it's argument. We pass the actual return value to it. To learn more about this check the [meteor source code](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/meteor/helpers.js#L90) or [the fibers documentation on `resolver`s](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fibers#api-documentation)